# JavaScript: How do I concatenate two values from a single Object?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I know this is simple but for whatever reason I'm completely stumped right now.

I have an array of objects all with their own `month` and `year` properties and I'm trying to concatenate both from each object and then display them together. My data is as follows:

```
"caloriesBurned": [
        {
            "month": "Nov",
            "year": "2018",
            "calories": 64.15
        },
        {
            "month": "Dec",
            "year": "2018",
            "calories": 75.07
        }
]
```

Comment: Concatenate them in what way? Show what you're expecting the result to be.

Comment: `obj.caloriesBurned[i].month + obj.caloriesBurned[i].year`

Comment: You can try `console.log(caloriesBurned.map(item => item.month + " " + item.year));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
let arrayResult = []
for(let i=0; i< caloriesBurned.length; i++){debugger
    test = i+ ":->" + caloriesBurned[i].month + " " + caloriesBurned[i].year;
    arrayResult.push(test)
}
```

Or if need to use ES6 then just use map function, then no need to use for loop instead of that use map as a high order function and then can achieve that in more easy way, if not convinient with that, then can use above code as well .